# AJAX CORS http request nginx rejection

Tags: ajax, nginx, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, preflight

I've searched all the other related topics but can't find a solution to my specific problem.

I wrote a website containing AJAX http requests (get and put). The server getting those requests is nginx and running under debian.

Everything works perfectly as long as I advise my browser to ignore the Allow-Access-Header rejection. But if I don't let the browser ignore it. This happens:

```
Failed to load http://***/api/devices/7: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://***' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is my nginx configuration file, it's running on a z-wave base station so all the other configuration is related to that:

```
worker_processes 1;

error_log /dev/null;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

client_max_body_size 300M;

    access_log /dev/null;

    upstream hcserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:11111;
        keepalive 15;
    }


    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        proxy_read_timeout 400;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        location /api/service/ {
            rewrite ^/api/service/(.*) /services/system/$1.php;
        }

        location /api/service/backups/ {
            rewrite ^/api/service/backups/(.*)$ /services/system/backups.php?id=$1;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://hcserver;
            proxy_http_version 1.0;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_buffering off;

            error_page 502 =503 /vendor/en/home/503.html;
        }

        location / {
            root   /var/www/;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
             }
             if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
             }

            location ~* \.(css|js|html)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age:0, no-cache, no-store";
                add_header Pragma no-cache;
                add_header Expires 'Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT';
            }

            ssi on;
            ssi_value_length 2056;

            error_page  404              /vendor/404.html;
        }

        location ~* \.sh$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        location ~* \.php\?.* {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }

        rewrite ^/vendor/icons/User(.*) /vendor/icons/userIcons/User$1;
        rewrite ^/vendor/icons/rooms/User(.*) /vendor/icons/rooms/userIcons/User$1;
        rewrite ^/vendor/icons/scena/User(.*) /vendor/icons/scena/userIcons/User$1;
        rewrite ^/vendor/n_vicons/User(.*) /vendor/n_vicons/userIcons/User$1;
        rewrite ^/vendor/data_request(.*)php(.*) /api/mobile$2;
        rewrite ^/vendor/(js/)(.*) /vendor/js/$2 last;
        rewrite ^/vendor/([a-z][a-z]/)(.*) /vendor/$2;
    }
}
```

kind regards and please do not hack my IP: 127.0.0.1 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation in your config is a little off, but it looks to me like you're only adding the CORS headers inside the `location /` block. As a starting point, try elevating those headers to the `server` block, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range";
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
```

Now, these rules will apply to every location block for this server (and for every `$request_method` as well).

If you need context-specific rules - different CORS header values for different endpoints, for example - this is still a good place to start because it will validate the catch-all solution. Once you have *something* working, it's easier to make small changes to your rules while testing to figure out where things break down.

Hope this helps. If not, an update to your question including a full `curl` - headers and bodies for both the request and response - would be really helpful.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had no idea because I've never configured nginx before and feel so stupid right now. There was also another problem because I send Authorization header which isn't allowed with  Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*' ...

Comment: Glad to help! It's confusing at first, but will be second nature before long. I'm glad you mentioned authorization: if you're credentialing users (say, by setting a cookie), you'll also need to pass the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header. The line should look like this: `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";`. (You're exactly right that the wildcard won't work in that case.)